# How to selectively set chart color background?

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-charts

I have a chart which contains BarMarks within a certain "live data domain".
However, the `.chartXScale` adds a bit of domain left and right of that domain, let's call it "displayed domain".

What I want to achieve now is that:

- left of the "live data domain" there is light gray background
- within the "live data domain", there is a colored background
- right of the "live data domain", there is a light gray background again

Any idea how to get there?

--edit--

[image]

In this picture, the "live data area" is between the 11th and 17th. I want that area to have one background color, while the areas left and right of these dates shall be in another one.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot highlighting which part of the chart is the "live data domain"? Also, show a [mcve].